# android telnet console port 5554 from remote server: Connection closed by foreign host

Tags: android, adb, emulation, telnet

everyone! I am trying to telnet android emulator console port 5554 from remote server. It connected, but auto closed.

```
telnet remote_ip 5554
```

Returns:

```
Connected to remote_ip.
Escape Character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Meanwhile, telnet adb port

```
telnet remote_ip 5555
```

is okay!

So, why?  Thx for any advice.

Comment: Maybe the program listening on port 5554 expects you to send something?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude what exactly is that, the link doesn't say anything about telnet. [android-developer](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html)

Comment: I just tried on the same server with emulator:   telnet localhost 5554. That's okay. So it's that because the adb console-port limit to only local visit?

Comment: Then the question is, how long did you wait from connection to connection closed? Did the disconnect happen immediately?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes, is immediately closed. As I said, telnet 5555(adb port), same way is okay!

Comment: Then go to the server, the system you attempt to connect to, and check the logs. Or the logs of the firewall. Or of all firewalls between your local system and the remote system.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude en, thx buddy, u're right, maybe i have to check the firewall or public-cloud-platform for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you check with `netstat` you'll see `emulator` is only listening on `localhost`

```
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.5554         *.*                    LISTEN
```

so you won't be able to connect from a different host.

Comment: That should mean that `telnet` should not even be able to connect at all, and the output from `telnet` would be different.

Comment: Aah, actually, the connect is okay. I have add a tcp redirect for 5554 with 0.0.0.0:5554.  Also, the telnet shows connected, only problem is auto-closed.